# Peculiar behavior of nested class pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, heap-memory, mysql-connector

I'm using mysql-conntector++ and I'm interested by some of the behaviors of the pointer types such as:

```
sql::Driver *driver__;
```

or

```
sql::Connection *connection__;
```

Clearly `::Driver` and `::Connection` are nested classes of `sql`, when I attempt to initialise either of these pointers on the heap:

```
sql::Driver *driver__ {new sql::Driver()};
```

Error:

```
error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type ‘sql::Driver’
    sql::Driver *driver__ {new sql::Driver()};
```

How do libraries implement this type of behavior with nested classes and pointers to such classes?

I've looked over the mysql-connector++ source code and can't seem to identify the relevant section.

N.B the above errors have been produced using CMake with `-std=c++14`

Comment: I have no idea of mysql-connector++, but it appears that `sql::Driver` is an abstract class (has at least one pure virtual function), so you cannot create instances of it. This is true for classes in general, regardless of their scope.

Comment: Evidently the library creates objects of derived classes, and uses pointer upcast (which is implicit) to store the pointer in a `sql::Driver*`.

Comment: If the program compiled, the variable name `driver__` would cause the program to have undefined behaviour, because that name is reserved to the implementation. You should come up with another variable name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do libraries implement this type of behavior with nested classes and pointers to such classes?

Concrete instances of abstract classes only exist as a base class sub-object. The way to make those is inheritance:

```
struct MyDriver : sql::Driver {
    //TODO implement all pure virtual functions of sql::Driver
}

// imaginary implementation
Driver* get_driver_instance() {
    static MyDriver instance;
    return &instance;
}
```

---

PS. The fact that `Driver` is a member of `sql` (namespace?) is not significant to the user in other way, except the way it affects name lookup.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, when you declare

```
sql::Driver *driver__;
sql::Connection *connection__;
```

you declare references to instances which implement interfaces of:

- a SQL driver
- a SQL connection

In order to instanciate such instances, the library provides you factories in this way

```
driver__ = get_driver_instance();
connection__ = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "root");
```

Once instanciated, you'll manipulate only the public interfaces of such instances.